# Codeigniter: where to store session files

Tags: php, session, driver, codeigniter-3

To use the session library in CI 3, you need to set the session save path.

Where should I save the sessions? (path)

Maybe can somebody why I should use the database driver to save sessions because it's better?

Comment: in my experience db backed sessions are much faster - depending on traffic to your site, it also prevents the problem of running out of directory entries in the filesystem.  Not sure if that last one is still a problem or not.

Comment: @TimG As an addition to your comment, depending on your scale, DB backed sessions provide flexibility when it comes to load balancing across multiple web servers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
$r = implode('/', array_slice(explode('/', $_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"]),0,-1));
$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'my_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 14400;
$config['sess_save_path'] = $r.'/session/';
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 600;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
```